# 2 functions on Promise chaining are being called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, promise

I am learning javascript Promise. I have created 2 independent functions and am chaining them in a promise function. However the second function gets called first even though it is in the second then() block.

Code is below.

```
const one = document.getElementById('one');

function clkw(a){
    setTimeout(() => {
        one.innerHTML = a;
        return 2*a;
    }, 2000);
}

function clkw2(b){
    setTimeout(() => {
        one.innerHTML += ' '+b;
    }, 2000);
}

function trypromise(){
    const np = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            resolve(10)
        }, 2000);
    });

    np
        .then(function(data){
            return clkw(data);
        })
        .then(function(bata){
            clkw2(bata);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to chain and still be able to execute async code in the `then` continuation, you have to return a promise that resolves only when the result is ready.

In your snippet you don't actually return any values (or promises) from chained `then`s that can be used down the pipeline. Because of that, the result is automatically converted to a resolved promise that doesn't have any value.

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one');

function clkw(a){
    return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          one.innerHTML = a;
          res(2*a);
      }, 2000);
    });
}
function clkw2(b){
    return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          one.innerHTML += ' '+b;
          res();
      }, 2000);
    });
}
function trypromise(){
    const np = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            resolve(10)
        }, 2000);
    });

    np
    .then(function(data){
        return clkw(data);
    })
    .then(function(bata){
        clkw2(bata);
    });
}
trypromise();
```

```html
<div id='one'></div>
```

Comment: OK got that. Each function should have a promise. Thanks Wiktor :-)

Comment: Then() itself returns a promise. So if there were fetch calls it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

> However the second function gets called first even though it is in the second then() block.

Everything works as expected in the code you provided. How did you observe the strange behavior?

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one');

function clkw(a) {
  console.log("clkw");
  setTimeout(() => {
    one.innerHTML = a;
    return 2 * a;
  }, 2000);
}

function clkw2(b) {
  console.log("clkw2");
  setTimeout(() => {
    one.innerHTML += ' ' + b;
  }, 2000);
}

function trypromise() {
  const np = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(10)
    }, 2000);
  });
  np
    .then(function(data) {
      return clkw(data);
    })
    .then(function(bata) {
      clkw2(bata);
    });
}

trypromise()
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
```

Comment: Marzelin i get a undefined in the second response.